# Batch Resize Images Web Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, image-upload, sharepoint-integration

We have a requirement to resize images sent from devices before they are stored in SharePoint 2013.

Is there a web service that can be called that can adjust/resize the images consistently prior to storage?

If so, can you provide an example of calling this web service in your answer?

Comment: Do you have custom component that is used for uploading them in the first place or should they be resized after user has uploaded them to SP using default upload functionality?

Comment: No. Uploading by calling the existing SharePoint web service copy.asmx from another custom application outside SharePoint.